# sporadic not authorized errors with artifactory

Tags: artifactory

About 1 of 40 build on our CI server (and on developer machines) fails with:

[ERROR] Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-failsafe-plugin:2.17 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-failsafe-plugin:jar:2.17: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-failsafe-plugin:pom:2.17 from/to artifactory (https://example.com/artifactory/repo): Not authorized , ReasonPhrase:Unauthorized.

Still no clue how to fix it. Any ideas?

```
Storage Info:

Database Type:  postgresql 
Connection Url:  jdbc:postgresql://postgresql:5432/artifactory 
Storage Type:  file-system 

System Properties:

artifactory.running.mode:  OSS 
artifactory.running.state:  Online 
PID:  213 
artdist:  zip 
artifactory.home:  /opt/jfrog/artifactory 
artifactory.version:  5.5.1 
awt.toolkit:  sun.awt.X11.XToolkit 
catalina.base:  /opt/jfrog/artifactory/tomcat 
catalina.home:  /opt/jfrog/artifactory/tomcat 
catalina.useNaming:  true 
common.loader:  "${catalina.base}/lib","${catalina.base}/lib/*.jar","${catalina.home}/lib","${catalina.home}/lib/*.jar" 
derby.language.logStatementText:  false 
derby.module.mgmt.jmx:  org.apache.derby.impl.services.jmxnone.NoManagementService 
derby.storage.pageCacheSize:  500 
derby.stream.error.logSeverityLevel:  0 
file.encoding:  UTF8 
file.encoding.pkg:  sun.io 
file.separator:  / 
java.awt.graphicsenv:  sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment 
java.awt.headless:  true 
java.awt.printerjob:  sun.print.PSPrinterJob 
java.class.path:  /opt/jfrog/artifactory/tomcat/bin/bootstrap.jar:/opt/jfrog/artifactory/tomcat/bin/tomcat-juli.jar 
java.class.version:  52.0 
java.endorsed.dirs:  /opt/jfrog/artifactory/tomcat/endorsed 
java.ext.dirs:  /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext:/usr/java/packages/lib/ext 
java.home:  /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre 
java.io.tmpdir:  /opt/jfrog/artifactory/tomcat/temp 
java.library.path:  /usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/jni:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/jni:/lib:/usr/lib 
java.naming.factory.initial:  org.apache.naming.java.javaURLContextFactory 
java.naming.factory.url.pkgs:  org.apache.naming 
java.protocol.handler.pkgs:  org.apache.catalina.webresources 
java.runtime.name:  OpenJDK Runtime Environment 
java.runtime.version:  1.8.0_131-8u131-b11-2-b11 
java.security.egd:  file:/dev/./urandom 
java.specification.name:  Java Platform API Specification 
java.specification.vendor:  Oracle Corporation 
java.specification.version:  1.8 
java.util.logging.config.file:  /opt/jfrog/artifactory/tomcat/conf/logging.properties 
java.util.logging.manager:  org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager 
java.vendor:  Oracle Corporation 
java.vendor.url:  http://java.oracle.com/ 
java.vendor.url.bug:  http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/ 
java.version:  1.8.0_131 
java.vm.info:  mixed mode 
java.vm.name:  OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 
java.vm.specification.name:  Java Virtual Machine Specification 
java.vm.specification.vendor:  Oracle Corporation 
java.vm.specification.version:  1.8 
java.vm.vendor:  Oracle Corporation 
java.vm.version:  25.131-b11 
jdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize:  2048 
jruby.compile.invokedynamic:  false 
line.separator:  

org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.UDecoder.ALLOW_ENCODED_SLASH:  true 
org.jboss.logging.provider:  slf4j 
os.arch:  amd64 
os.name:  Linux 
os.version:  3.16.0-4-amd64 
package.access:  sun.,org.apache.catalina.,org.apache.coyote.,org.apache.jasper.,org.apache.tomcat. 
package.definition:  sun.,java.,org.apache.catalina.,org.apache.coyote.,org.apache.jasper.,org.apache.naming.,org.apache.tomcat. 
path.separator:  : 
server.loader:  
shared.loader:  
spring.beaninfo.ignore:  true 
sun.arch.data.model:  64 
sun.boot.class.path:  /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/resources.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/rt.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/sunrsasign.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/jsse.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/jce.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/charsets.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/jfr.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/classes 
sun.boot.library.path:  /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64 
sun.cpu.endian:  little 
sun.cpu.isalist:  
sun.io.unicode.encoding:  UnicodeLittle 
sun.java.command:  org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start 
sun.java.launcher:  SUN_STANDARD 
sun.jnu.encoding:  UTF-8 
sun.management.compiler:  HotSpot 64-Bit Tiered Compilers 
sun.os.patch.level:  unknown 
tomcat.util.buf.StringCache.byte.enabled:  true 
tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanFilter.jarsToScan:  log4j-web*.jar,log4j-taglib*.jar,log4javascript*.jar,slf4j-taglib*.jar 
tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanFilter.jarsToSkip:  bootstrap.jar,commons-daemon.jar,tomcat-juli.jar,annotations-api.jar,el-api.jar,jsp-api.jar,servlet-api.jar,websocket-api.jar,catalina.jar,catalina-ant.jar,catalina-ha.jar,catalina-storeconfig.jar,catalina-tribes.jar,jasper.jar,jasper-el.jar,ecj-*.jar,tomcat-api.jar,tomcat-util.jar,tomcat-util-scan.jar,tomcat-coyote.jar,tomcat-dbcp.jar,tomcat-jni.jar,tomcat-websocket.jar,tomcat-i18n-en.jar,tomcat-i18n-es.jar,tomcat-i18n-fr.jar,tomcat-i18n-ja.jar,tomcat-juli-adapters.jar,catalina-jmx-remote.jar,catalina-ws.jar,tomcat-jdbc.jar,tools.jar,commons-beanutils*.jar,commons-codec*.jar,commons-collections*.jar,commons-dbcp*.jar,commons-digester*.jar,commons-fileupload*.jar,commons-httpclient*.jar,commons-io*.jar,commons-lang*.jar,commons-logging*.jar,commons-math*.jar,commons-pool*.jar,jstl.jar,taglibs-standard-spec-*.jar,geronimo-spec-jaxrpc*.jar,wsdl4j*.jar,ant.jar,ant-junit*.jar,aspectj*.jar,jmx.jar,h2*.jar,hibernate*.jar,httpclient*.jar,jmx-tools.jar,jta*.jar,log4j*.jar,mail*.jar,slf4j*.jar,xercesImpl.jar,xmlParserAPIs.jar,xml-apis.jar,junit.jar,junit-*.jar,ant-launcher.jar,cobertura-*.jar,asm-*.jar,dom4j-*.jar,icu4j-*.jar,jaxen-*.jar,jdom-*.jar,jetty-*.jar,oro-*.jar,servlet-api-*.jar,tagsoup-*.jar,xmlParserAPIs-*.jar,xom-*.jar 
user.dir:  / 
user.home:  /home/artifactory 
user.language:  en 
user.name:  artifactory 
user.timezone:  Etc/UTC 

General JVM Info:

Available Processors:  2 
Heap Memory Usage-Committed:  536870912 
Heap Memory Usage-Init:  536870912 
Heap Memory Usage-Max:  4294967296 
Heap Memory Usage-Used:  301045776 
Non-Heap Memory Usage-Committed:  226463744 
Non-Heap Memory Usage-Init:  2555904 
Non-Heap Memory Usage-Max:  -1 
Non-Heap Memory Usage-Used:  220772408 

JVM Arguments:

Args:  -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/opt/jfrog/artifactory/tomcat/conf/logging.properties
-Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
-Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=****
-Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources
-Xms512m
-Xmx2g
-Xss256k
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:OnOutOfMemoryError=kill -9 %p
-Djruby.compile.invokedynamic=false
-Dfile.encoding=UTF8
-Dartdist=zip
-Dorg.apache.tomcat.util.buf.UDecoder.ALLOW_ENCODED_SLASH=true
-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom
-Xmx4g
-Dartifactory.home=/opt/jfrog/artifactory
-Dfile.encoding=UTF8
-Djruby.compile.invokedynamic=false
-Djava.endorsed.dirs=/opt/jfrog/artifactory/tomcat/endorsed
-Dcatalina.base=/opt/jfrog/artifactory/tomcat
-Dcatalina.home=/opt/jfrog/artifactory/tomcat
-Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/jfrog/artifactory/tomcat/temp
```

Comment: When this happens, what does your request.log say? The file is located in "ARTIFACTORY_HOME/logs/request.log" and will at least tell you the HTTP response code.
Also, what users are granted access to this file? Are the client credentials users authenticated against LDAP / ActiveDirectory?

Comment: 20171116122845|1|REQUEST|10.0.1.122|non_authenticated_user|GET|/repo/org/apache/maven/maven-plugin-api/2.0.6/maven-plugin-api-2.0.6.jar|HTTP/1.1|401|0

Comment: They are authenticated against AD. All users are in the same group and have the same permissions. This error occurs on CI server builds with the same service user and local builds. The files differ.

Comment: I would look closely at any authentication error from the AD.
Can you ask some users to generate their API keys and use that instead?

Comment: You mean API key or password? we use the encrypted passwords in our maven settings. Isn't the API Key only for the REST API?

Comment: Interesting.. as I can see API key and encrypted password works for maven settings. So should we use the encrypted password or the API key? I can change the settings on our buildserver if you like. Is API key more stable or what's the point?

Comment: For actual users I would recommend API keys (keys are stable compared to passwords that may change often in corporate settings, they can be revoked and recreated if leaked...). For CI / buildservers, the official recommandation is access tokens, because they allow accounts that are not attached to actual users. Both solutions don't reauthenticate against the AD so might solve your sporadic errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are using the API key instead of the encrypted password on our CI server now. Thanks to @ajeans.